# Arduino http request LED

Tags: arduino

Forgive me I am very new c/Arduino, for my first project I have placed a php file on my server. When the page returns "ON" I would like the built in LED to be turned on and conversely when the response is "OFF" then the LED should be off.

At the moment the LED remains on despite the response being returned as off.

I cannot figure out why this could be

Any help much appreciated.

```html
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>

void setup() {
  // Bridge takes about two seconds to start up
  // it can be helpful to use the on-board LED
  // as an indicator for when it has initialized
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  Bridge.begin();
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);


  SerialUSB.begin(9600);

  while (!SerialUSB); // wait for a serial connection
}

void loop() {

  // Initialize the client library
  HttpClient client;

  // Make a HTTP request:
  client.get("http://www.***.co.uk/arduino.php");

  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    String response = String(c);
    Serial.print(response);


    if(c == 'OFF'){
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    }else{
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    }
  }
  SerialUSB.flush();

  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: the php file (while testing) is simply: <?php echo "OFF"; ?>

Comment: You are storing the server response in a variable of type `char` - it is utterly impossible for a single character to be equal to `OFF`!  I can't imagine how you even got this code to compile, with that type mismatch.

Comment: Hi jasonharper, thank you for pointing that out, if you would like to submit that as an answer I would be more than happy to mark it. thanks again.

Comment: As @jasonharper said, `c` is a `char`, change your php to answer just a  `char` and test it.